# Subtracting times in Excel inconsistently shows pound signs or 0:00:00 when duration is 0 seconds. How do you prevent pound signs?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I have an excel spreadsheet with a Start Time  and End Time column. I'm trying to add a "Duration" column which obviously subtracts the Start Time from the End Time.

In some instances the result is 0:00:00 which is fine. The issue is that in other instances the result should be the same but instead it's showing as pound signs.

Why am I getting varying results when doing the same thing? I want all my 0 second durations to show as 0:00:00 and not as a bunch of pound signs.

Data:

[image]

- Start and End dates are both formatted "Time" values.
- They contain dates and times, only Time is shown
- Dates are all the same across start/end times.
- There is a custom format applied to the Duration of [h]:mm:ss
- Formula in 'Duration' column is just B2-A2 filled down
- The value in A2 is `11/17/2021  9:58:46 AM`
- The value in B2 is `11/17/2021  9:58:46 AM`
- The value in A7 is `11/17/2021  10:10:24 AM`
- The value in B7 is `11/17/2021  10:10:24 AM`

Comment: Have you tried making the duration column wider?

Comment: I discovered the issue. My "dates" were actually much more precise. if I change the formatting to number the time ROUNDED up to those H:mm:ss values but the end time is actually behidn the start time so the result is negative.

Comment: You can answer your own question ...

Answer (score 2):

The displayed Date and Time is actually rounded up from a much more specific time stamp (milliseconds). Changing the Time format to "Number" revealed that the END time was actually BEFORE the start time and the result was a negative time value.

Excel just displays the data in the format chosen so this was not inherently obvious:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah changing the format of the cell to number can reveal a lot about how excel is handling the data from the date.